# SQL CAST or Convert Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-server-2000

Hi i am new to SQL and need to convert the following cast statement from `varchar(255)` to `decimal(6,2)` i tried many options but couldn't achieve it

```
case when [ A 2 cost] = ' £-   ' then '0' else [ A 2 cost] end as Costing
```

the result of `[A 2 Cost]` in destination is `decimal(6,2)` datatype but in source it is `varchar(255)`

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)

Comment: what do you mean by `[ A 2 cost]` ?

Comment: it is a column name

Comment: Please give some examples of data which could be in `A 2 cost`. What are the problems you have at the moment? Are you aware, that you are using blanks *within* your column's names (before the `A`), but not everywhere?

Comment: the column is from a flat file and it has values like  £-   and  £105.55 and the blank is just a typo from me ignore the blanks inside column names and i am getting Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: Another question please, what is the purpose of ` = ' £-   ' ` ? do you want to cast if the columns doesn't look like this ?

Comment: By the way, it goes a LONG way for people here to help you with your question if you give as much information as possible. In this case, it would be a big help to give a description of the table (the data model) and some background information (perhaps the purpose of the table and an explanation of the mysterious column names)

Comment: I think he want to cast only if the column value doesnt contain ' £-   ' ... other wise he is going to cast

Comment: I see this question is tagged Sql Server 2000. Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    case when [ A 2 cost] = ' £-   ' 
then 0.0 else cast([ A 2 cost] as decimal(5,2)) end as Costing
```

if the other columns contains £ in the beginning you need to clean it:

```
    case when [ A 2 cost] = ' £-   ' 
then 0.0 else cast(REPLACE([ A 2 cost],'£','') as decimal(5,2)) end as Costing
```

Comment: TY sorry i couldn't explain the issue clearly in question as i am a novice to this area but u sorted it rightly..